# Rollover image swapping as a field

Tags: media

I'm learning Drupal and I'm trying to create a field where I can upload 2 images and let one face into the other while I mouse over/ hover / rollover it. Then I eventually plan to make it into a views like one in Zappos where the user can see alternate views on mouse over.

I've looked up the other thread and found the Rollover filter on Drupal but I still don't know how to make that work. I need it as a field of a node so that I can display a view of all the related nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work!
I added CSS code found here into the global.css of my theme:

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg7

```
#cf {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

And later I used the Custom Formatter module as recommended by jpelan to add this html code from that same website.

```
<div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="/images/Windows%20Logo.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="/images/Turtle.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set it up as a single image field with two values and then use https://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters to create a custom formator for that field and do a display hide/show with css or jquery.

Comment: Thanks! The module looks promising but I'm not sure how to do a display hide/show with my imagefield. I've found examples here http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg1 but I'm still not sure how to do it since the formatter uses PHP and html+tokens

Comment: In other words, how do I proceed from there?

Comment: If your images are always going to be the same size, says 100x100, you could have a parent wrapper div and then a child div containing both images. Then use position absolute to move the child div within the parent div. Something like this:  

    `<div class="wrapper" >
<div class="child" >
<img ... /><img ...>
</div></div>`  

then in css  

`.wrapper { width:100px; height:100px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; }
.child { position:absolute; top:0; right:0;}
.child:hover { right:100px; }`